# How to send mails with Excel without seeing the virus scanner message in the email

Tags: excel, vba

I setting up a vba script inside an Excel macro that it sends bulk mails.

I am using Microsoft Office Home and Business 2013 on Windows 7.

```vb
Public mails_list As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set mails = New Collection
End Sub

Sub invioNuovaProd()

    Dim OutMailArray(200)

    Dim OutApp As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 2 To 200
    Cells(i, 25).Value = i
       If Cells(i, 11) = "x" Then
         Set OutMailArray(i - 2) = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
        With OutMailArray(i - 2)
          .To = Cells(i, 12)
        '    .CC = ""
        '    .BCC = ""
            .Subject = Cells(i, 13)
            .Body = Cells(i, 14) & vbNewLine & "Ordine: " & Cells(i, 15) & vbNewLine & "Articolo: " & Cells(i, 16) & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 17) & vbNewLine & "Quantità in produzione: " & Cells(i, 18) & vbNewLine & "Consegna prevista: " & Cells(i, 19) & vbNewLine & "-----------" & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 20) & vbNewLine & "-----------" & vbNewLine & Cells(i, 21)
            .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send   
        End With
        End If
    Next i
    On Error GoTo 0

End Sub
```

With the code that I wrote , now I can send the mails, but the server virus scanner detects my bulk mails, adding the following lines inside the body of each mail:

```
A known virus was discovered and deleted. Virus-scanner messages follow:
Clamd found the Heuristics.OLE2.ContainsMacros virus.
```

How can I avoid this?

Comment: "How can I avoid this?" Don't send a virus. • If it is a false positive report this file to your virus scanner company so they can remove the false positive or create an exception in your virus scanner for that file. • Alternatively remove the macros from the files you want to send.

Comment: Yeah , I noticed that i didn't skip the line with the  ".attachment .add" command. i close the question. Thanks  for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The active file is an Excel with macro activated.

I skipped the line:

```
 .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove that message from your mail, using Excel, since it is generated by your virus scanner, and not Excel.

Simply don't send viruses, or report the file as a false positive to your anti-virus provider.
If you know for sure, that your file doesn't contain virus, and it is your code giving off the warning, remove the code from your file.
The VBA statement, 'Kill', is known to virtual always trigger anti-virus software to mark an Excel workbook as virus infected.  Also many API calls has that effect.